# Regex Replace variable number of ****** with predefined digits

Tags: c#, regex, linq

```
var panmaskednumber = "543034******0243"; Console.WriteLine(panmaskednumber.Count(x => x == '*'));
var pattern = "\\*";
var replace = "123456789";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var newnumber = reg.Replace(panmaskednumber, replace,panmaskednumber.Count(x => x == '*'));
Console.WriteLine(newnumber);
```

I'm trying to Replace * in var panmaskednumber(coming from DB with symmetric key).

Not liking to use the Contains approach in which I'm specifying number of * 6 / 7 with multiple If-elseif. Since those can vary between 6,7-9.

With my above approach it replaces for each char of -> * with var replace.
Any Linq approach if there is highly appreciated.
Result something: 5430341234567890243

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: 5430341234567890243 4

Comment: Can you change your code to be [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i will try mate

Comment: Using regex : string input = "var panmaskednumber = \"543034******0243\"";
            string replacement = "345678";

            string pattern = @"(?'prefix'\d+)(?'wildcard'\*+)(?'suffix'\d+)";

            string output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"${prefix}" + replacement + "${suffix}");

Comment: What sould be the output if `*`'s count is greater that replace's length?

Comment: You should be more specific about the input and desired output. *"Result something"* did not make clear the dependency between the number of * and the digits you expect as a replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `\*+` pattern that will match 1 or more asterisk symbols:

```
var panmaskednumber = "543034******0243";
var replace = "123456789";
var res = Regex.Replace(panmaskednumber, @"\*+", replace);
// res => 5430341234567890243
```

See the [C# demo.](https://ideone.com/LFpFz2)

If the number of asterisks to be replaced depends on the `replace` length, you may pass the match value to the match evaluator and perform necessary manipulatons there:

```
var panmaskednumber = "543034*****0243";
var replace = "123";

var res = Regex.Replace(panmaskednumber, @"\*+", m => 
      m.Value.Length <= replace.Length ? 
        replace.Substring(0, m.Value.Length) : 
        $"{replace}{m.Value.Substring(replace.Length)}"
    );
Console.Write(res);
// "543034***0243" / "123456789" -> 543034 123 0243
// "543034*****0243" / "123" -> 543034 123** 0243
```

See [antother C# demo](https://ideone.com/6R8Trx)

Comment: The expected out would be 543034**123456**0243 - the OP wants to replace the exact number of asterisk symbols with the matching number of digits.

Comment: @Filburt [That's not what he says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370036/regex-replace-variable-number-of-with-predefined-digits#comment73801940_43370036)

Comment: Well, if the number of asterisks to be matches depends on the `replace` length, it still can be managed. Let me update.

Comment: @Rawling OP has some difficulties explaing but states *"Since those can vary between 6,7-9."* and *"With my above approach it replaces for each char of -> * with var replace."*

Comment: You can replace string.Format with an interpolated string.

Comment: @aloisdg: Yes, [`$"{replace}{m.Value.Substring(replace.Length)}"`](https://ideone.com/6R8Trx) will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew better isn't it :)

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew,. and all who gave their valuable input. I got some better pointers with your help to go forward. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regex, but you can achieve without. Lets go for a simpler solution. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dv5cqH).

```
var panmaskednumber = "543034******0243";
var count = panmaskednumber.Count(x => x == '*');
var start = panmaskednumber.IndexOf('*');   
var replace = "123456789";

// output 5430341234567890243 (543034 123456789 0243)
Console.WriteLine(panmaskednumber.Remove(start) // get head
                + replace // add replace
                + panmaskednumber.Substring(start + count)); // add tail

 // output 5430341234560243 (543034 123456 0243) // get head 
 Console.WriteLine(panmaskednumber.Remove(start)
                + replace.Remove(count) // add replace with count respect
                + panmaskednumber.Substring(start + count)); // add tail

 replace = "123";

 // output 543034123***0243 (543034 123*** 0243) // get head 
 Console.WriteLine(panmaskednumber.Remove(start)
                + replace // add replace
                + new string('*', count - replace.Length) // fill with missing *
                + panmaskednumber.Substring(start + count)); // add tail
```

> "I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail."

*[Law of instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)*

Dont use Regex, if you don't have too. For this problem, C#.NET is enough. :)